# Quickest way to get element by index in QuerySet

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm trying to create time-efficient searching function for my system in Django considering that there are approximately 5 million objects.

This is how i set query up:

```
objects_found = (Model.objects.extra(where=["CHAR_LENGTH(attribute) > 300"])).filter(attribute__trigram_similar=query)
```

I know that this QuerySet is yet not completely evaluated, and that's exactly what i don't want.

For example, to complete evaluate the set up QuerySet like this:

```
list(objects_found)
```

It takes around ~60 seconds.

If i want to get first item of the set up QuerySet in a classical way, it will still takes ~60 seconds, since the query is initiated for all of the objects:

```
objects_found[0]
```

But if i utilize methods like `first()`:

```
objects_found.first()
```

It takes around ~9 seconds, meaning that full QuerySet is not evaluated.

---

Let's consider that `objects_found` has 500 objects. What if i need to do something like this:

```
objects_found[40]
```

or this:

```
objects_found[:15]
```

in a time efficient way?

p.s slicing does create offset option at db level, but there is no difference in time for some reason.

Therefore instead of searching through all 500 objects, the code will only search through `40` or `15` objects.

Is there any implementation in Django QuerySet for this to be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit query by slicing it out as presented in [limiting querysets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets) documentation

```
objects_found = (Model.objects.extra(where=["CHAR_LENGTH(attribute) > 300"])).filter(attribute__trigram_similar=query)[:15]
```

Your query is pretty hard on database also functions like CHAR_LENGTH are not so optimal to run each query runtime so you could probably extract length to a integer row instead of doing CHAR_LENGTH.

Regarding the trigram you could create index 
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/pgtrgm.html#AEN143603

Also if you prefer creating indexes through Django following resource could be useful
https://vxlabs.com/2018/01/31/creating-a-django-migration-for-a-gist-gin-index-with-a-special-index-operator/

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work, it takes as much time as full list to load. (I didn't downvote your answer by the way).

Comment: @ShellRox it is expected that following will take long as you probably don't have indexes set, you should try to optimize your query with  trigram index and also you can convert char length into field to get faster results

Comment: Thank you for suggestion! do you know how can i utilize trigram index? I can't find it anywhere. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/indexes/

Comment: There is no official migration setup for the following but I have attached resource that seems to be useful if you dislike setting indexes manually

Comment: Sorry for my lack of experience in databases. Is this indexing permanent for each database? For example will it permanently sort them by db command?  Or they should be executed on every query

Comment: To simplify it up, index is a data structure that helps searching faster on topic/column it is set for ( there is a lot of resources online regarding following and I suggest you pursue reading regarding DB stuff because it is important to understand optimizations)

Comment: As i understand indexing sorts the columns in database based on some value? If i may ask, by what value may it sort columns?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164994/discussion-between-iklinac-and-shellrox).

Comment: I tried executing `CREATE INDEX trgm_idx ON table USING gist (column gist_trgm_ops);` and it seems to be taking quite a long, i guess its sorting all the data?